# fullScreenCover not being dismissed inside a Navigation- or TabView

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to dismiss a `fullscreenCover(..)` that is nested within a TabView and a NavigationView. I want it to be dismissed by invaliding a parent-view of the view invoking `fullScreenCover(..)`.

For example this view hierarchy works fine and dismisses fullScreenCover on invaliding view X:

- X -> A -> fullScreenCover

This view hierarchy does not dismiss fullScreenCover on invalidating view X:

- X -> NavigationView -> A -> fullScreenCover

It seems like `fullScreenCover` uses UIKit under the hood, and that the PresentationHostingController does not get dismissed properly when a NavigationView is used. I provided some example code that shows the problem:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var viewFullScreen: Bool = false
    @State var showViewA: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        if showViewA {
            NavigationView{
                Button("Trigger fullscreen") { viewFullScreen.toggle() }
                .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $viewFullScreen) {
                    Button("Go to B", action: {
                        self.showViewA = false //Not working when embedded in NavigationView
                    })
                }
            }
        } else {
            Text("View B")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the sample code works fine for me

Comment: I am using Xcode 13.2.1, with iOS 15.2.

Comment: I tried to set viewFullScreen = false, before going triggering view B. 

It seems like there then is a race condition with the fullScreenCover dismissal, and the root view rebuilding itself. It all works if ok, if I delay triggering view B. Seems a bit hacky though :/

Comment: Works fine on latest Xcode

Comment: I tried the code again with latest Xcode 13.3.
It works on simulator. But not on real device

Comment: is your device on 15.4?

Comment: It was on iOS 15.3.1. I tried it on device with iOS 15.4, and it worked! So in conclusion the bug will still appear on iOS versions below <15.4 but fixed after that.